# Deleting null characters from cstring

Tags: c

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>



int main()
{
    TCHAR* greeting = L"HELL\0O W\0ORLD!";

    wprintf(L"%s\n",greeting);

    _wsystem(L"pause");
    return 0;
}
```

How to remove all null characters(except of trailing) in "greeting"? I would like to avoid creating function from scratch. I mean the C++ counterpart of PHP's str_replace.

Comment: You can't have a C string with null characters in it. A null character terminates the string. You will need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
TCHAR greeting[] = L"HELL\0O W\0ORLD!";
TCHAR *writepos = greeting;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(greeting) - 1; ++i) {
    if (greeting[i] != 0) {
        *writepos++ = greeting[i];
    }
}
*writepos = 0;

wprintf(L"%s\n",greeting);
```

The important point is that you need to remove the nul characters when you still know the length of the data. We can easily get the size of a string literal (or in my code, a copy of a literal) using `sizeof`, and that includes the nul terminator. If the input is not really a string literal, but was read from somewhere, you need to know the size of the data read.

If you ever pass a pointer to the data without the length, then you're done for. You can't recover the length once you've lost it.

C has no standard function to remove particular characters from either a string or a buffer. C++ has `std::remove_copy_if`, but I expect that's no use to you.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, after

```
TCHAR* greeting = L"HELL\0O W\0ORLD!";
```

the length of the string is lost. The runtime will only see

```
greeting == L"HELL"; //HA!
```

You need to store the length of the string and manually shift the characters.

Comment: + 1 for demonic reference :-)